# What is the purpose of adding capacitance to stepper motor windings?

Tags: capacitor, stepper-motor, motor-controller, stepper-driver

I am looking at the schematic of the [DRV8434SEVM](https://www.ti.com/tool/DRV8434SEVM) evaluation board for the [DRV8483S](https://www.ti.com/product/DRV8434S) stepper motor driver and I see they've put these 3.3nF capacitors on the outputs going to the stepper motor coils. I cannot find any mention about doing this in the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/drv8434s) of the driver or anywhere else, why might you want to do something like this?
[image: outputs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printed (PDF) schematic shows these are DNP (do not place), so it seems a non-issue.

Perhaps they are available as an option to slow edge rate from the inverters.

I wouldn't recommend it myself; it's a crude method that increases switching loss.

Better is a series inductive element (which limits current drawn from the inverter, thus having less impact on efficiency), placed before the capacitor, with damping provided either by using a lossy inductive element like a ferrite bead, or an R+C in parallel with the C.

Comment: @greybeard thanks!